# Simple class inheritance in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance

I am fairly new to Python and OOP. Suppose I have two classes, `Base1` and `Base2`. Suppose also that `Base1` has computed some values `a1`, `b1` and that `Base2` has a method that multiplies two values. My question is, what is the correct way of passing `a1` and `b1` of `Base1` to multiply in `Base2`?

One way to do this by defining a derived class, `Derived` as follows:

```
class Base1:
    def __init__(self, x1 , y1):
        # perform some computation on x1 and y1
        # store result in a1 and b1
        self.a1=x1
        self.b1=y1

class Base2:
    def __init__(self, x2 , y2):
        self.a2=x2
        self.b2=y2
        self.c2=self.multiply(self.a1,self.b1) # using a1 and b1 of Base1

    def multiply(self, p,q):
        return p*q

class Derived(Base1,Base2):
    def __init__(self):
        self.describe='Derived Class'
        Base1.__init__(self,3,4)
        Base2.__init__(self,5,6)
```

Then:

```
f=Derived()
f.c2=12
```

However, in a more complex situation, it is easy to lose track of where `self.a1`, `self.b1` came from. It is also not obvious to me why the two base classes can access the attributes and the methods of each other in this way?

Edit: This is Python 2.7.10.

Comment: Use "private" variables like `__a1`.

Comment: there is nothing like *private* in python

Comment: If this is 2.x Python, you need to use `object`. Also, you should read up on `super`. As it stands, `Base2.__init__` will never be executed.

Comment: You're not adding any value, @Shadowfax. I intentionally quoted private because it isn't private in the usual sense. Would you like to add a reference to Python's handling of variables starting with double underscores?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Oops, I missed that!

Comment: Please specify if this Python 2 or 3. Also, check your indentation: `multiply()` should likely be indented.

Comment: Thanks for the useful comments. @jonsharpe I have edited the post to execute Base2.__init__(). @ Mike Müller, indeed,  I have edited the post.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Firstly, it's really name mangling. Like everything else, it's still possible to access the variable if you know how it does the rename. (A simple `dir` on the object is enough to find the real name.) So Shadowfax is correct; there's no *real* private. It's all just conventions. Secondly, "private" variables are *discouraged* in Python. You should only make a variable private if you have a *reason* to (restrictions on values you need to enforce, needs to be immutable, etc.). And the normal way to do that is with the conventional single underscore: `_a1`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt [Name mangling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) is primarily intended for avoiding clashes between a class and its subclasses, though, not for some kind of "privacy" indicator.

Comment: @Abbas that's a long way from what I was suggesting - again, read up on `super`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Python is dynamic. It doesn't check if attributes are present until the actual line of code that tries to access them. So your code happens to work. Just because you can do this, **doesn't mean you should**, though. Python depends on you to make good decisions in organizing your code rather than trying to protect you from doing dumb things; we're all adults here.

#### Why you can access variables

The reason really boils down to the fact that Python is a *dynamic* language. No types are assigned to variables, so Python doesn't know ahead of time what to expect in that variable. Alongside that design decision, Python doesn't actually check for the existence of an attribute until it actually tries to access the attribute.

Let's modify `Base2` a little bit to get some clarity. First, make `Base1` and `Base2` inherit from `object`. (That's necessary so we can tell what types we're actually dealing with.) Then add the following `print`s to `Base2`:

```
class Base2(object):
    def __init__(self, x2 , y2):
        print type(self)
        print id(self)
        self.a2=x2
        self.b2=y2
        self.c2=self.multiply(self.a1,self.b1) # using a1 and b1 of Base1

    def multiply(self, p,q):
        return p*q
```

Now let's try it out:

```
>>> d = Derived()
<class '__main__.Derived'>
42223600
>>> print id(d)
42223600
```

So we can see that even in `Base2`'s initializer, Python knows that `self` contains a `Derived` instance. Because Python uses duck typing, it doesn't check ahead of time whether `self` has `a1` or `b1` attributes; it just tries to access them. If they are there, it works. If they are not, it throws an error. You can see this by instantiating an instance of `Base2` directly:

```
>>> Base2(1, 2)
<class '__main__.Base2'>
41403888
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in __init__
AttributeError: 'Base2' object has no attribute 'a1'
```

Note that even with the error, it still executes the `print` statements *before* trying to access `a1`. Python doesn't check that the attribute is there **until the line of code is executed**.

We can get even crazier and add attributes to objects as the code runs:

```
>>> b = Base1(1,2)
>>> b.a1
1
>>> b.notyet
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Base1' object has no attribute 'notyet'
>>> b.notyet = 'adding an attribute'
>>> b.notyet
'adding an attribute'
```

#### How you *should* organize this code

`Base2` should not try to access those variables without inheriting from `Base1`. Even though it's possible to do this if you only ever instantiate instances of `Derived`, you should assume that someone else might use `Base2` directly or create a different class that inherits from `Base2` and not `Base1`. In other words, you should just ignore that this is possible. A lot of things are like that in Python. It doesn't restrict you from doing them, but you shouldn't do them because they will confuse you or other people or cause problems later. Python is known for not trying to restrict functionality and depending on *you*, the developer, to use the language wisely. The community has a catchphrase for that approach: we're all adults here.

I'm going to assume that `Base2` is primarily intended to be just a mix-in to provide the `multiply` method. In that case, we should define `c2` on the subclass, `Derived`, since it will have access to both `multiply` and the attributes `a1` and `b1`.

For a purely derived value, you should use a `property`:

```
class Derived(Base1,Base2):
    def __init__(self):
        self.describe='Derived Class'
        Base1.__init__(self,3,4)
        Base2.__init__(self,5,6)

    @property
    def c2(self):
        return self.multiply(self.a1,self.b1) # using a1 and b1 of Base1
```

This prevents callers from changing the value (unless you explicitly create a setter) and avoids the issue of tracking where it came from. It will always be computed on the fly, even though using it *looks* like just using a normal attribute:

```
x = Derived()
print x.c2
```

This would give `12` as expected.

Comment: jpmc26, many thanks for the excellent answer. Assuming, however that Base2 is primarly intended to be just a mix-in is not accurate. In general, I am assuming Base2 will take some output of Base1, say noisy signal, and perform some complex filtering etc.

Comment: @Abbas In general, if you have computed things, it's better to compute them on the fly or cache them in a place that has access to all the data necessary. Computing on the fly when you can has major advantages in terms of giving you less to think about keeping organized; if you have to cache it, you need to make sure that you recalculate it anytime some of the inputs change, which is a lot more work keeping it organized in your head and your code. I would still try to keep that state on `Derived` for that reason; `Base2` will never have any idea when the state changes.

Comment: You might also consider composition over inheritance. You might do just as well to have an *instance* of `Base2` stored in an attribute on `Derived` instead of inheriting from it. In the absolute *worst* case where you can't change how the classes are organized, you should *at least* pass the needed values into `Base2`'s initializer instead of referencing them directly. (Frankly, over the last few years, I've developed a strong distaste for Object Oriented code. I believe it's *very* rarely more useful than a more functional minded approach.)

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2 **always** inherit from `object`. Otherwise you get old-style classes which should not use:

```
class Base1(object):
    def __init__(self, x1 , y1):
        # perform some computation on x1 and y1
        # store result in a1 and b1
        self.a1 = x1
        self.b1 = y1

class Base2(object):
    def __init__(self, x2 , y2):
        self.a2 = x2
        self.b2 = y2
        self.c2 = self.multiply(self.a1, self.b1) # using a1 and b1 of Base1

    def multiply(self, p,q):
        return p*q

class Derived(Base1, Base2):
    def __init__(self):
        self.describe='Derived Class'
        Base1.__init__(self, 3, 4)
        Base2.__init__(self, 5, 6)
```

Python looks for methods using the method resolution order (mro). You can find out the current order:

```
>>> Derived.mro()
[__main__.Derived, __main__.Base1, __main__.Base2, object]
```

That means Python looks for a method `multiply()` in the class `Derived` first. If it finds it there, it will use it. Otherwise it keeps searching using the mro until it finds it. Try changing the order of `Base1` and `Base2` in `Derived(Base1,Base2)` and check how this effects the mro:

```
class Derived2(Base2, Base1):
    pass


>>> Derived2.mro()
[__main__.Derived2, __main__.Base2, __main__.Base1, object]
```

The `self` always refers to the instance. In this case `f` (`f = Derived()`). It does not matter how `f` gets its attributes. The assignment `self.x = something` can happen in any method of any of the classes involved.

Answer (score 0):

You can just provide a method `multiply` in the base class which assumes that `a1` and `b1` has been defined in the base class.
So the code will be like

```
class Base1(object):
    def __init__(self,a1,b1):
        self.a1 = a1
        self.b1 = b1

class Base2(Base1):

    def multiply():
        return self.a1*self.b1
```

Here as you havent provided a `__init__` for base2 it will use the init method of base1 which takes in parameters as `a1` and `a2`

so now

```
base = Base2(5,4)
print(base.multiply())
```

Comment: In general, Base2 is more complex, it  will take some output of Base1, say noisy signal, and perform some complex filtering etc.